# бросает NPE при обращении к переменной не ссылочного типа

Tags: java, android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int com.watabou.pixeldungeon.actors.Char.pos' on a null object reference
    at com.watabou.pixeldungeon.Dungeon.switchLevel(Dungeon.java:139)
    at com.watabou.pixeldungeon.scenes.InterlevelScene.descend(InterlevelScene.java:140)
    at com.watabou.pixeldungeon.scenes.InterlevelScene.access$1000007(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.watabou.pixeldungeon.scenes.InterlevelScene$100000000.run(InterlevelScene.java:65)

лог ошибки, код бросать бессмысленно.
во-первых его очень много, во-вторых пусть это и маразм, но int переменная была явно инициализирована, пусть это и не обязательно.

мне интересно, из-за чего подобное может возникать, возможно я обращаюсь к ней раньше, чем инициализирован обьект, но тогда NPE бросал бы сам обьект.

это игра на java под платформу андроид. пишу в среде раздаботки AIDE, на самом же андроиде.

Comment: *но тогда NPE бросал бы сам обьект* - не может бросить NPE объект, которого не существует. Бросает код, который обращается (то есть хочет обратиться) к его членам через `null`-ссылку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Я вам посылку принес. Только я вам ее не отдам ..."*

---

`null`, конечно, не `pos`, а `Char`.

> Attempt to write to field 'int
>   com.watabou.pixeldungeon.actors.Char.pos' on a null object reference

означает:

> Попытка записи в поле ... объекта по `null` ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за разъяснения.
Когда работаешь на двух работах, пропускаешь совсем очевидные вещи. А ведь я даже не вчитался в лог ошибки, просто увидел `NPE` - и мне хватило.